# manipulate parameters in sh

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sh

I'm working with a utility ([unison](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison), but that's not the point) that accepts parameters like:

```
$ unison -path path1 -path path2 -path path3
```

I would like to write a sh script that I could run like this:

```
$ myscript path1 path2 path3
```

I'm hoping for a Posix compliant solution, but bash-specific would also be good.

I'm guessing it should be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
unison ${*/ / -path }
```

But this doesn't work.

**EDIT**: OK, I think I got something:

```
#!/bin/bash
PARAMS=
for arg in "$@"
do
    PARAMS+=" -path '$arg'"
done
unison $PARAMS
```

The problems are this only works in bash, and I'm pretty sure there's a better way to quote the parameters.

Comment: Are you hoping for a one-line solution that doesn't involve a `for` loop?

Comment: Introducing the single quotes is probably a bad idea.  As written the quotes are seen by the unison  command, which is not what you want.  Protecting the outside of the argument with single quotes is OK if you do not have any single quotes in the arguments - but your probably need an eval to get it to work correctly.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 is of interest here -- even though not all its answers are applicable on POSIX sh, its explanation of what problems your proposed solution have are entirely relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unchecked, it could be as simple as:

```
exec unison -path $1 -path $2 -path $3
```

If you don't embed spaces in your path names, then you can deal with a variable number of arguments with:

```
arglist=""
for path in "$@"
do
    arglist="$arglist -path $path"
done
exec unison $arglist
```

If you have spaces in your path names, then you have to work a lot harder; I usually use a custom program called `escape`, which quotes arguments that need quoting, and `eval`:

```
arglist=""
for path in "$@"
do
    path=$(escape "$path")
    arglist="$arglist -path $path"
done
eval exec unison "$arglist"
```

I note that using Perl or Python would make handling arguments with spaces in them easier - but the question asks about shell.

It might also be feasible in Bash to use a shell array variable - build up the arguments into an array and pass the array as the arguments to the `unison` command.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Bash's arrays, all your quoting problems go away.

```
#!/bin/bash
args=()
for i in "$@"; do
    # With Bash >= 3:
    args+=(-path "$i")
    # +=() doesn't work in Bash 2
    # args=("${args[@]}" -path "$i")
done
exec unison "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: Ditto @Gordon, plus thanks for including the bit about Bash 2 compatibility!

Answer (score 3):

In Bash, you can use `"${@/#/-path }"` which will replace the beginning of each positional parameter with "-path ". To represent the end of the string use `%` instead of `#`.

Here is a simple demo script using `sed` and repeated `-e` options. (Of course there are more efficient ways to use `sed`.)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Resulting arguments: ${@/#/-e }"
sed "${@/#/-e }"
```

And running it like this:

```
$ echo abc | demo s/a/A/ s/b/B/
```

We get:

```
Resulting arguments: -e s/a/A/ -e s/b/B/
ABc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a heavily bash-specific version, you can try

```
#! /bin/sh

eval eval exec \
  unison -path\\ \\\"{$(eval echo \\\"\\\${1..$#}\\\" | sed 's/ /,/g')}\\\"
```

If you remove all the triple-backslash-quoted characters, this becomes easier to understand, but I won't spoil the fun by explaining it :-)

The main complication is to handle file names with spaces. That accounts for the triple-backlash quoting and double eval.

Comment: WTF? If you're going to be bash-specific, the Right Thing is to use arrays -- that way you get the benefit of a simple, easy-to-read code that can be written clearly to obviously have no bugs, rather than needing to rely on having no obvious bugs.

Comment: That answer was meant to be strange, cryptic and humorous, not an example of the "Right Thing".

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can satisfyingly quote your characters:

```
job_strategy()
{
  local p
  for p in "$@"; do
    printf '-path\000%s\000' "$p"
  done
}

job_process()
{
  xargs -0 unison
}

job_strategy "path1" "path2" "path3" | job_process
```

Comment: +1. That said, is `xargs -0` POSIX? My impression is that it's a GNU extension.

Comment: It's not listed in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/utilities/xargs.html

Comment: Uppps, I misquoted the FreeBSD manual page: it should be `POSIX.2`.